# Sqlite query for getting index from sorted result

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to make a sql query were in I have a table which consists below columns

```
id    Name        Color
1     Water       red
5     Sun         blue Light
7     Fire        green
10    Wter       red
21    Son         blue Light
24    Fore        green
```

So the requirement is I have a record say

```
5     Sun         blue Light
```

Now I need to get the index of above record from the sorted result of the Name. Say below can be the select query.

```
SELECT * FROM  MYTABLENAME WHERE COLOR LIKE “blue/%” ORDER BY Name ASC
```

Note:- I cannot load all the records in my memory and iterate as the records can be huge at times. So need to come up with a query that gives the exact indexof the record without loading the records.

Thanks In advance

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you need the index for?

Comment: From the position of the record I have to show in the UI to the user like " 50 of 1000".

Comment: Why can't you simply increase a variable by 50 whenever you go to the next page?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't stored the sort result in a temporary table, the only way to do this is to count how many records would be sorted before this record:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MYTABLENAME
WHERE COLOR LIKE “blue/%”
  AND Name <= 'Sun'
```

Comment: But do you see the `<=`? It does not matter in which order the records are counted, the sum is the same.